# What Actionscript APIs will help to fetch more content at the end of animation

Tags: actionscript

I have my own swf content. Now I want pull some adverts from my server which is to be played at the end. How can I do this without having the original fla file with which the content was created.

Maybe I need to create another swf containing the original swf content and then catching an event which indicates the end of animation of the original swf and then pulling the advert from the server.

But then what is the event that I should catch and which apis will help me request the server and then again start playing with the content from the server. I read some where that loadMovie is to be used, but not sure of the event and the sequence of things that needs to be done to achieve my goal

Answer (score 0):

"Maybe I need to create another swf containing the original swf content and then catching an event which indicates the end of animation of the original swf and then pulling the advert from the server."

Sounds about right, except that your new swf doesn't need to "contain" the first swf, you can simply load it.

You will need to dispatch an event when the first animation is complete. Since you don't have access to the original fla, it will depend on the type of the animation. If it's a frame based animation, it's all good, you'll just have to check for the last frame of the movie, otherwise you may be out of luck... Even if it's a frame based animation , you may still encounter problems, if the animation contains various MovieClips with different animation lengths. It still may be possible to find out when the end occurs but it may be a bit more complex and the solution not that pretty.

"which apis will help me request the server and then again start playing with the content from the server."
That would depend on the server and the type of content...